# Help installing Piwik (Php / MySQL) on a Windows 2003 R2 SP2 Server IIS

Tags: windows-server-2003, php, iis, piwik

I've tried using XAMPP to install this app, locally on my computer, and it works.
But when I get to the server, XAMPP is not what I need to use PIWIK (it's like a google analytics clone). It's based on PHP and MySQL. But I require to install it in a Windows 2003 R2 SP2 Server using IIS.
I've tried several things to add an extension that servers PHP in Windows IIS.
But nothing makes it work. It's always the ERROR 400 and everything seems fine.
All the tutorials talk about a ISAPI PHP but I don't see that in the version I downloadedhttp://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed and [Edit powers activate! Removing Hi/Thanks](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/876/edit-powers-activate-removing-hi-thanks) today.

Can someone help me with really good clear instructions? I'm lost and I really need to get this moving as soon as possible, any volunteers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen Microsoft's site regarding [PHP on IIS](http://php.iis.net/)? I've been able to get Piwik working on PHP/IIS on Server 2003 SP2 (I'm not sure whether R2 makes a difference, but I doubt it) by installing FastCGI and then installing PHP.

Comment: Had to install SmarterSTATS on IIs. Tried several solutions , configurations, etc. After installing apache and php, tried with mysqlserver and it seems like I could never install some thing called 'mysqli' ...so we gave up.